# SQL Merge, Table Value Parameters and GetDate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, table-valued-parameters

I have some synchronization processes which make use of a "LastUpdate" flag to update any records that have changed since the last sync attempt.

A little while back I updated the code to utilize table valued parameters, rather than synchronizing (add/updating) a row at a time. This is 10 times or more faster.

However, I have now come across a race condition which sometimes causes updates to be missed. I quickly rustled up some SQL script to test my situation/theory (any large table with IDs will work):

```
/*CREATE TYPE IntTable AS TABLE(
[RequestID] [int] NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE MergeTest(
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[RequestID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PreDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[MergeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
GO
*/

DECLARE @requestIDs As IntTable

INSERT INTO @requestIDs
SELECT RequestID FROM Request

DECLARE @preDate As DateTime = Getdate()

MERGE INTO MergeTest USING @requestIDs SRC
ON MergeTest.RequestID = SRC.RequestID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET PreDate = @preDate, MergeDate = GetDate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (RequestID, PreDate, MergeDate)
     VALUES (SRC.RequestID, @preDate, GetDate());

SELECT TOP 100 * FROM MergeTest
```

Example Result

```
ID  RequestID   PreDate                 MergeDate
1   169880      2016-05-13 13:57:54.643 2016-05-13 13:57:54.643
```

So, you can see that the MergeDate (GetDate()) is from when the merge starts, not when it ends.

The race condition can be this:

```
Check what has been updated since 14:59
Start a merge at 15:00
Check what has been updated since 15:00
Merge completes, but with a LastUpdate of 15:00
Check what has been updated since 15:01
```

All of the records from the merge would be skipped. In reality, this race condition very rarely occurs because we are talking milliseconds rather than minutes, but it does happen.

The question is... without running a second script to re-update the LastUpdate with a post-merge date, is there any way to get the merge statement to use the date that it finished the job rather than when it started it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `LastUpdate` (or `MergeDate`, in your sample code), to `getdate()`, do something like this:

```
declare @MergeDate DateTime = getdate()

<merge code...>
set MergeDate = @MergeDate
<...>
```

That way, the timestamp is equal to when the merge began, not ended.  You may then process some rows more than once, but that's an error of inclusion instead of exclusion, and should have no impact on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to force SQL to use the end time in the merge (which I can't see you doing), why not store the start time of each merge in a table (lets call this `dLastRunDate`).

When you start the next merge, don't use getdate() -- grab the `dLastRunDate` from the new table and use that to check for new records.

Then at the end of the job, update `dLastRunDate` to its new value.

We use this approach in our warehouse ETLS.  Each step has an entry in the table.  Every time the job starts a step, it picks up its own `dLastRunDate` and uses that to check for updated records.  When the step is done, it updates `dLastRunDate` with its start time.